# Flash game lagging in chrome on Mac

Tags: macos, actionscript-3, google-chrome, memory-leaks

I have created a simple flash game similar to shooting balloons. You can find one example on this [site](http://www.vivacashgames.com/games/gameplay/id/291). My game is working fine on windows in all browsers(locally & on server) and it is also working fine on Mac in safari & firefox but game is completely unplayable in chrome on Mac.

Is this because of memory leaks in my game or is this the problem of chrome on Mac.

And how can i trace memory leaks in my game. It is coded in AS3 using Flash CS5.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed.. not playable with mac/chrome (ver 15.0.874.120) flash (ver 11.1.102.55).

You can try Monster Debugger:
http://demonsterdebugger.com/

Its quite easy to use.

But first.. my guess is that you have something in your main gameloop (onEnterFrame, timer). You can try to remove things from your gameloop piece by piece until you catch the problem.

EDIT:
I tried your game again, and i believe the problem is somewhere how you handle the hearts, perhaps you have forgot to removeChild or some listeners when hearts are dropped, and off the screen.

Comment: Thanks Jarno for your reply. But I looked at my code again and i think i am removing them completly after they drop down. I am using the same code in other game also but again problem is same but this time in shooting canon.Here is the [link](http://www.viewpointadvisors.com/gumball/)

Comment: You can find my .as file at this [link](http://www.viewpointadvisors.com/gumball/Game.as) if you want to look at it.

Thanks

Comment: well all the code didnt open up for me, but i suppose you should optimize at least moveShootingBall() function. Its called in main game loop, right? Perhaps some of variables could be declared as class var, so they wont be declared each time the gameloop call moveStoothingBall. Here is some tips for optimize your loop: http://blog.coursevector.com/notes-general-as3-tips

Comment: the other game was not so laggy.. but it was also pretty much unplayable after a while. Next level gave fresh start thought..

Comment: I tried commenting the code step by step as you said and i found that when the code which is responsible for "ball explode" is not commented than the game lags alot.But still i am not getting that what is wrong in that. The link for Game.as file is not working for you?

Comment: I have optimized the moveShootingBall() function but still no success.

Comment: lagging feels reeeealllly random, after i tried the game again. After like twenty quick plays couldnt find the pattern. One thing i noticed.. could be random,but.. try to take all away from container that comes down with time (ugly fellow and all that other stuff there :)

Comment: oh, and link for Game.as works just fine. All the _code_ just didnt "open up" for _me_ :) Perhaps tomorrow, i'll check it again.. but there was nothing exactly wrong as far as i could say. If i remember correctly, there was few New Point here and there.. check out those, declare them as class var, and change values like myPoint.x = 1, myPoint.y = 22.. nothing but guessing :)

Comment: I guess lagging is not random.When i comment the whole code except the ball destroy part,lagging continues but if i comment that part,the remaining game works fine.And i removed many new Points & everything from the container that are coming down but still no success :(

Comment: I have commented the moveBalls() function which responsible for moving balls & other things down with time,And it works but still cant figure out what is wrong in that.

Thanks

Comment: finally i got it...problem occured because of rendering of balls.I was using updateAfterEvent() function to update the display list in moveBalls() function.By removing that it is working fine in all browsers(Mac & windows) :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Flash uses a garbage collector for managing memory. That means that memory leaks do not exist by definition, everything that is in memory is being referenced somewhere. There's no way for an external tool or application to know whether or not an object in memory should be referenced.

What you can do is run your game through a profiler (flash builder has one) that will track your application's memory usage and with that you might figure out what you're forgetting to clear reference (`var = null` or `mc.removeChild(var)`).

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you're not clearing or recycling bitmap data, or some other object, when it's no longer useful, which results in adding more and more data to memory (often in an Enter Frame event handler) and causes major performance issues as we see here.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply.I have checked the code again and i didnt find anything missing.I am using Enterframe event listener in timeline to update the timerbar in the game just below the Score.But even if i comment that whole code..nothing changes. Here is the[link](http://www.viewpointadvisors.com/gumball/Game.as) of my Game.as file.Perhaps you will get better idea of my problem.
Thanks